# Why do classes that implement an interface not count as the same type as the interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I have

```
out.load(output, transactions, columnHeaders, dataFormat);
```

Where `load` is defined as:

```
public boolean load(String outputfile, List<Transaction> transactions, List<String> columnHeaders, String dataFormat);
```

and

```
String output = "";
String dataFormat = "";
ArrayList<ARTransaction> transactions = new ArrayList<ARTransaction>();
List<String> columnHeaders = null;
```

where

```
ARTransaction implements Transaction
```

Why is there a problem on the type of `transactions`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public boolean load(String outputfile, List<? extends Transaction> transactions, List<String> columnHeaders, String dataFormat);
```

Or just declare transactions as a `List<Transaction>`.

Here's the common example of why you obviously can't do this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> objList = list; //if this were possible
objList.add(Integer.valueOf(5));
String val = list.get(0);  //ClassCastException here
System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: Ah.  That fixes the problem.  ty to both of you.  You mean if I wanted to add `BRTransaction t` to `transactions` in the method `load`.

That makes sense :-p

Comment: Does that mean that Java will consider transactions to be of type List<ARTransaction> in `load`?

Comment: No, Java will think it is a List of some unknown subclass of Transaction.  The actual type in this case will be unknown to `load`.  If it matters, consider adding a type parameter to the load method (`T extends Transaction`).

Comment: That's neat.  So the type of transaction actually changes (upwards) dynamically! *right?*

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by that so I can't confirm or deny its correctness.

Comment: No, there is nothing dynamic about it. It happens via type erasure at compile time.

Comment: Cool.  Ok.  I need to go outside.  I'm getting excited by Java types.

Comment: Nice writeup.  Maybe use `Comparable` instead of `Object` to make it clearer how your example relates to interface types as type parameters since `Comparable` is an interface type that `String` implements whereas `Object` is not an interface type.

Answer (score 3):

It is having difficulties casting the contravariant type that is from `ArrayList<ARTransaction>` to `List<Transaction>`.

Try `List<? extends Transaction>` instead

Answer (score 2):

Because it may not satisfy the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).