# Java generics and upcasting

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

Can somebody explain me why this

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();
```

generates a type mismatch error ?

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap< String,LinkedList< String>> to Iterators.Map< String,List< String>>

Hashmap implements the Map interface, and LinkedList implements the List interface. Moreover, this

```
List<String> foo = new LinkedList<String>();
```

works...

Thanks

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225511/why-do-classes-that-implement-an-interface-not-count-as-the-same-type-as-the-inte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this like the following:

`Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`

Pay attention that I changed `LinkedList` to `List` in the right side of your assignment.

You are right that LinkedList implements List. But I think that explanation of this error is not in definition of List but in definition of interface `Map<K,V>`.

The left side of your expression says that you want to create Map of String and List, i.e. `V` is "replaced" by List. Right side uses LinkedList. Although LinkedList implements List it does not work because the definition of Map is not something like `Map<K, V extends List>`, so compiler requires exact match.

I am not sure that my description is strict enough, but anyway this is the way to right generics. Really, when you create map of list you do not care about the implementation of List, therefore say `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. Only when you create instance of List care about its implementation. This will allow you to change the implementation if future without modification of other code.

Comment: You're right in your last comment, I should not care about the exact type when instanciating the map. But I tried youre solution about a couple a minutes ago, and again I got a type mismatch error:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,List<String>> to Iterators.Map<String,List<String>>`

Comment: @Simon: It looks like you have imported the wrong `Map` class; I'm not sure what `Iterators.Map` is but you want `java.util.Map`.  Sorry that we all missed that in your original message.

Comment: Crap... 45 mins of work lost because of the Eclipse completion... Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: @Mark, I think you are right, but he more likely imported wrong List: java.awt.List instead of java.util.List. This is what I do at least once a day...

Comment: @Alex: I know I am right (look at the error message referencing "Iterators.Map") and he didn't import `List` incorrectly since that part works fine for him (see last code segment of question).  But I make the `java.awt.List` mistake a lot too.

Answer (score 6):

Because a `Map<String, List<String>>` allows you to `put` an `ArrayList<String>` into it, but doing so would violate the type integrity of a `HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>`.

Either declare your `HashMap` as a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` or your variable as a `Map<String, LinkedList<String>>` or `Map<String, ? extends List<String>>`.

### Edit

The more immediate problem is that you have imported the wrong `Map` class (something called `Iterators.Map`) or you have another class (or inner class rather) called `Map` in the same package as this code.  You want to import `java.util.Map`.

Comment: I didn't think about that. But in this case, the solution AlexR should work, right ? Did I reached a limit of the Java type checking ?

Comment: @Simon: I'm not sure how his solution differs from my suggestions, but yes `HashMap<String, List<String>>` will work if you don't to know that the lists will be `LinkedList`s (and after you fix the import error you have as I commented on Alex's answer).

Answer (score 4):

In Java , Generics does not preserve subtype-covariance. So , if B is a subtype of A , Gen(B) may not be subtype of Gen(A) where Gen is some form of a Generic usage of a type.

Concretely , if `LinkedList` is a subtype of `List` , that does not imply that `Map<String,LinkedList>` is a subtype of `Map<String,List>`. As other posts have suggested , you have to use `List` as your type in the `HashMap` type parameters.

Comment: Yes, but (keeping B a subtype of A) B<T> should be a subtype of A<T>. Obviously this is not true in Java JDK 1.6

Comment: @Simon: actually it *is* true.  That doesn't mean a `B<V extends T>` is type-assignable to an `A<T>` though.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Interface for the HashMap:

```
Map<String, List<String>> foo = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> bar = new LinkedList<String>();

foo.put("barkey", bar);
```

Comment: Thanks, as I told AlexR, I tried that and it gives me the same type mismatch error..